# In Elixir, how to mock a function that was defined in a 'used' module?

Tags: elixir, meck

I'm using [meck](https://github.com/eproxus/meck) and it works great in most cases. However, I encountered the following error:
`elixir
(ErlangError) erlang error: {:undefined_function, {OAuth2.Strategy.AuthCode, :new, 2}}`

I found that `:new` was a function defined in `OAuth2.Strategy`'s `__using__` macro. That means `:new` wasn't defined `OAuth2.Strategy.AuthCode`. How do I mock out `:new` in this case?

Comment: Can't you mock the module where it was defined on? Maybe OAuth2.Strategy.new?

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't work. I guess it's cos `new` is defined only when `OAuth2.Strategy` is used. Had to rely on creating another module and placed all the relevant code in a function there and mocking it out in my tests.

Answer (score 3):

Meck creates mocks in runtime, thus it will never be able to mock macros in Elixir. If your macro eventually creates a function, that is then compiled into a module, you should be able to mock that (provided that you know the name of the function).